# What's this Switch / Outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Probably more curiosity than necessity but what was this switch?  And what might it been used for. I swear I've seen this type before,  but cannot remember if I ever knew. Might be helpful to know when it's time to remove it.  Thanks!  [image]

Comment: Does it move?  I imagine it might be some kind of push/pull switch.

Comment: Or it might twist. Or it might be an odd variant on the "needs a tool to switch it tamper-resistant" given the slot. If it IS a switch,  it switches whatever might be connected to it. Could be it's some variant on old TV/radio antenna flat wire connector (without the wire attached anymore on this side) if it's not a switch, and that's what the slot is for. Whatever it is, it's odd enough that I'm getting no useful matches on reverse image search.

Comment: Where in your house is it? Might be another clue.

Comment: Perhaps its a dummy plug blocking a socket.  Its been there so long, it looks like its part of the cover. Tty wiggling and pulling it.

Comment: Another option is to unscrew the faceplate and see what is behind there in the way of wiring (power vs phone vs ???).

Comment: Whatever it was, it wasn't installed correctly. Look at how those screw slots don't line up! ;)

Comment: Could it be a pull-switch to call for aid, or a plug left in an outlet, as for 300-ohm antenna twinlead? As others mention, it should be easy to remove the cover and peek behind.

Comment: I wish I had some answers to ask the comments but I'm away from the house for a good while.  I do remember pulling at it and it didn't want to budge though.  Didn't try twisting though.  It's located at light switch height next to the kitchen.  Oddly enough there is an empty outlet that was round directly below it.

Comment: It _almost_ looks like the kind of pull-cord switch that is put in hospital bathrooms that can be used to notify the nursing staff if someone has an issue (such as, "I've fallen and I can't get up") in a bathroom. _Almost_ but not quite.

Comment: @FreeMan Just because the screws aren't indexed doesn't mean that it was installed incorrectly.

Comment: There was a smilie at the end of that, @matt. I was only 3/4 serious... ;)